# Typeerror int is not callable

Tags: python, function, typeerror

I'm trying to write a program that uses a function to calculate simple interest based on the information the user inputs. I'm getting a TypeError- 'int' is not callable. I thought this error only happened when you named a variable int on accident, but I haven't done that so I'm not sure why I would be getting this type of error in my program. Code is below, any guidance is appreciated!

```
def accrued(p, r, n):
    percent = r/100
    total = p(1 + (percent*n))
    return total

principal = int(input('Enter the principal amount: '))
rate = float(input('Enter the anuual interest rate. Give it as a percentage: '))
num_years = int(input('Enter the number of years for the loan: '))
result = accrued(principal, rate, num_years)
print(result)
```

Comment: you miss the multiply operator `p*(1 + (percent*n))`

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `p(1 + (percent*n))` to mean? Now, look at the last word in the error message. Can you infer what it *does* mean? Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
total = p(1 + (percent*n))
```

to:

```
total = p*(1 + (percent*n))
```

Without the `*`, `p(...)` is parsed as a function call.  Since an integer is being passed as `p`, it's causing the error you're seeing.

Comment: Well that was a dumb mistake of me to make. Thank you, this fixed my program

Answer (score 1):

change total = p*(1 + (percent*n))

```
def accrued(p, r, n):
    percent = r/100
    total = p*(1 + (percent*n)) # * missing 
    return total

principal = int(input('Enter the principal amount: '))
rate = float(input('Enter the anuual interest rate. Give it as a percentage: '))
num_years = int(input('Enter the number of years for the loan: '))
result = accrued(principal, rate, num_years)
print(result)
```

Comment: What did you expect? Code only answer - no explanation - seemingly simple "copy&paste" of the code - no explanation whatsoever was fixed ...

Answer (score 1):

You get `principal` from the user via `int(input(...))` - so it is an integer. Then you provide it to your fuction:

> ```
> result = accrued(principal, rate, num_years)
> ```

as 1st parameter - your function takes the first parameter as `p`.

You then do

> ```
> total = p(1 + (percent*n))  # this is a function call - p is an integer
> ```

which is where your error stems from:

> TypeError- 'int' is not callable

Fix it by providing an operator like `*`

```
total = p*(1 + (percent*n))
```